# 64bit successor to bincalc for OS X

Tags: osx, calculator

There is an excellent binary calculator for OS X called [BinCalc](http://www.klsn.com/soporific/BinCalc.html). The primary problem with it is that it only supports 32-bit numbers.

I am wondering if there is a good successor to this calculator.

The primary features I am looking for are:

(0) Support 64bit numbers

(1) RPN

(2) The ability to see or edit multiple representations of at least the first two items on the stack at the same time. BinCalc, for example, shows long, hex, bit, float, unsigned, etc. representations.

(3) Standard binary operators (shift, and, or, etc.)